# maven shade plugin doesn't let me consume the reduced-dependencies.pom

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

After creating a jar with shade plugin, where I shaded a certain dependency, the reduced-dependencies.pom is generated and I would like to consume it in a different project.

I can't understand how this can be done, as **ONLY** the complete original pom gets to be installed (and later on deployed) to my .m2 repo. 
I have read and could not find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500735/what-is-dependency-reduced-pom-xml-file-which-created-when-calling-maven-packa/26501988#26501988), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904573/what-is-the-purpose-of-dependency-reduced-pom-xml-generated-by-the-shade-plugin) (where OrangeDog asked it inside the comments and wasn't answered) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990049/shade-plugin-harcording-dependency-for-excluded-artifact-also).

How can I use the reduced-pom instead of the original pom in a different project ???

Answer (score 1):

After some farther testing it seemed that the problem was found:
if you use the `<shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>` option in the shade plugin configuration then the shaded artifact is added near the original (non-shaded) artifact, and the original (non-shaded) artifact is the one that is being installed to .m2 along with the (non-shaded) pom.

In case not using this configuration (which is by default false), then the shade plugin behaves as expected:
there is only one artifact - the shade artifact - and it, along with its reduced-dependencies.pom gets to be uploaded to .m2, as expected.